# Как правильно отдавать стриминговые ивенты в python?

Tags: python

У меня будет приложение, которое будет принимать реквест от пользователя и возвращать стриминговые данные.

Это приложение будет принимать сообщение от пользователя (скажем в json формате), но возвращать ему будет не полний ответ, а по словам, т. е, чанками, пока не дойдет до конца возвращаемого сообщения.

Если я бы возвращал полный ответ, то создал бы простой REST API. В текущем случае, мне надо какое-то решение, которое бы возвращало стриминговые ивенты в ответ на запрос к серверу.

Я смотрел в в сторону server-sent events + `asyncio`. А так же на на сокеты.

Вопрос: как это можно реализовать с помощью `python`?
Буду благодарен за любые рекомендации или статьи по этому вопросу.

Благодарю

Comment: Вот пример сервера на flask, который на get запрос будет отдавать данные построчно: https://dev.to/anoff/how-to-create-a-streaming-http-interface-in-python--ceh#comment-2inm . На клиенте также нужно итеративно принимать, а не дожидаться ответа целиком. Вот тут по идее рабочий пример на requests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17823166/4752653 . Что-то подобное можно через aiohttp или httpx реализовать, и по идее на FastAPI вместо flask.

Comment: На FastAPI что-то подобное реализуется через StreamingResponse: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse . В общем, все реализуемо, но конкретная реализация зависит от выбранных клиентской и серверной http библиотеки.